# 273 + degree Celsius = Kelvin. Why 273?

Tags: water, temperature, units, definition, metrology

Temperature conversion:

$$273 + \text{degree Celsius} = \text{Kelvin}$$

Actually why is that $273$? How does one come up with this?

My teacher mentioned Gann's law (not sure if this is the one) but I couldn't find anything related to this, which law should it be?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics

Comment: @genneth: Triple point of water is 273.16K, to be precise.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius

Comment: see also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601223/the-definition-of-1-kelvin

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One Celsius (or Kelvin) degree as a temperature difference was defined as 1/100 of the temperature difference between the freezing point of water and boiling point of water.

We call these points 0 °C and 100 °C, respectively. The number 100 arose because we're used to numbers that are powers of ten because we use the base-ten system. The Celsius degree is "one percent" of the temperature difference.

There also exists the minimum temperature that one may achieve. In Kelvin degrees, it's sensible to call this minimum 0 K: that's a primary condition on the "natural" temperature scales such as the Kelvin scale. If one insists that one Kelvin degree is equally large as one Celsius degree as a unit of temperature difference, it just turns out that the melting point of ice has to be 273.15 K and the boiling point of water is 373.15 K. It's because the temperature difference between the boiling and freezing points is 2.7315 times smaller than the temperature difference between the minimum allowed temperature, the absolute zero, and the freezing point of water.

This number 2.7315 can't be explained in simple words. It is a fact about water, a fact of Nature that may be derived from the laws of quantum mechanics. One has to "simulate" what the water molecules are doing all over this large interval of temperatures and this is just what comes out. We know it is so from experiments.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why people don't go to a logarithmic scale (kind of like decibels), at least for low temperatures. Then there would be no lower limit.

Comment: Dear Mike, exponential notation is enough to deal with low enough temperatures. What's important is that temperature is just energy per degree of freedom and energy is additive. So all nonlinear redefinitions of $T\to f(T)$ would be unnatural. Also note that for the ideal gas, we have $pV=nRT$, so at a fixed pressure (or volume), the volume (or pressure) is proportional to $T$. We don't express pressures and volumes in terms of their logarithms, either, so it would be equally unnatural for the temperature.

Comment: The log scale is always a sort of "policymaking issue", making it easy for people to say simple numbers instead of powers of ten which are "complicated constucts" for most laymen. It's the only justification for decibels, pH, Richter scales, and other things: you just don't want the laymen to ever pronounce "ten to the power of [a number]", that's the only reason. But people achieved just a billionth of kelvin, that's the record, and those small numbers aren't extreme and one can express them in words like billionth without using "ten to minus [a big power]".

Comment: While historically 0°C was defined as the freezing temperature of water at normal pressure, the correct definition of the [Celsius scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius) actually takes the [triple point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point) of [Vienna Standard Mean Ocean Water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Standard_Mean_Ocean_Water) (around 0.01°C), since that can be meassured a lot more precise, while the freezing point requires an additional definition of standard pressure

Comment: @CrazyBuddy The [Wikipedia article on the Celsius scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius) is a good start

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - There is, in fact, a lower limit, regardless of how the scale is calibrated. Temperature is a measure of the transmissible energy contained in the molecules of a substance. It is theoretically possible for said molecules to have no detectable energy (all energy they do have is inherent in their atomic structure, is not transmissible, and to remove that energy would be to destroy matter); that's zero degrees of temperature. We've gotten to within a fraction of a degree last I checked. However, you can't have less than no energy.

Comment: Decibels are calibrated based on a "reference point", which can't be "absolute zero". 0 dBu ~= .776V; 0 dBV = 1V. 0 dB SPL = 20 uPa (the clinically-derived threshold of human hearing in a healthy young individual). In fact, decibels are eventually discarded when considering very small amounts, because an absolute zero would be -∞dB: the electromagnetic "noise floor" of the universe is typically expressed in degrees Kelvin instead of dBm (reference 1 milliwatt; a common standard for EM signal/noise strength).

Comment: @z_z Just remember Luboš's answer is a [simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children "You may call it a lie-to-children"), the second point is actually not the freezing point but the triple point of water. It doesn't change the first few digits of measurements, but it's very important if you're dealing with tiny temperature variations.

Comment: Dear Tobias, just to be sure, the Celsius scale was defined so that 0 deg C was the freezing point - it was until 1954. With this definition, the triple point was about 0.01 deg C. In 1954, the definition was changed but 0 deg C isn't the triple point. instead, 0.01 deg C accurately was fixed to be the triple point, so the freezing point is still approximately 0 deg C, with accuracy better than 0.01 deg C.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius_degree

Comment: Dear @Luboš, my [second comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37743/273-degree-celsius-kelvin-why-273/37745#comment82001_37745) was ambigous there, my [first one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37743/273-degree-celsius-kelvin-why-273/37745#comment81899_37745) already stated that the triple point was left at _exactly_ 0.01°C=273.16K and fixed (just like $c$). See http://www1.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter2/2-1/2-1-1/kelvin.html: **The kelvin, unit of thermodynamic temperature, is the fraction 1/273.16 of the thermodynamic temperature of the triple point of water.**

Comment: I believe that the triple point of water is 273.15 K.  At that point the vapor pressure is that of pure water and there is no extra gas present.  In actual use the triple point of water at *standard conditions* is 273.16 K.  The difference is that at standard conditions the pressure is 1 atm (or more recently, 1 bar).  The extra pressure is enough to raise the melting point of water 0.01 K.  As for the Kelvin scale it comes from Charles' Law for an ideal gas.  Basically it shows that the volume of an ideal gas shrinks to 0 at some temperature, taken to be 0 K.

Comment: Why we don't use the energy scale : $k_b=1$ ?

Comment: Particle physicists do, and they usually express energy - and therefore also temperature - in electronvolts and its power-of-ten multiples. Room temperature is about 0.025 electronvolts: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=288+kelvin+times+Boltzmann+constant+in+electronvolts

Comment: To be exact, the minimum temperature 0 K can not be archived! Near 0 K, it gets harder and harder to cool down further. 0 K means that particles do not move. It gets harder and harder to slow them down further.

Comment: Dear Volker, well, what you write is true only in some contexts with certain definitions of the temperature. In others, you can even achieve negative absolute temperatures.  LASERs often are said to have a negative temperature due to the population inversion https://www.google.com/search?q=laser+negative+temperature&oq=laser+negative+temperature&aqs=edge..69i57.2831j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 It's not quite right because only some states are counted, and very high-energy states are banned a priori ... Also, in QM, the question "is the temperature exactly zero" may have a finite probability!

Answer (score 1):

The Kelvin temperature scale is an absolute temperature scale.  That is 0 K is absolute zero.  It also has the property that temperature intervals on the Kelvin scale are the same as on the Celsius scale.  That is a decrease or increase of one Kelvin is the same as a decrease or increase of one degree Celsius.  To meet these two requirements it is necessary to choose 273.16 K as the temperature of the triple point of water.  According to Halliday and Resnick, "Fundamentals of Physics" second edition, 273.16 K was adopted as the temperature of the triple point of water at the Thirteenth General Conference of Weights and Measures in 1967 at Paris.

Answer (score -3):

Because it is the Celsius value at which all molecular moverment stops, aka absolute zero or 0 in kelvin scale

http://www.beyondmech.com/physics-mechanis/pm-topic-5.html

Comment: I am not sure what your answer adds to the already accepted one. You also give a link to a webpage, but there should be at least some explanation why you are linking to this specific page.