# Why is the absolute zero -273.15ºC?

Tags: water, temperature, units, definition, metrology

I can't find an answer of why the lowest temperature is -273.15ºC. Is it deduced theoretically or is it experimental?

An explanation is that when any gas volume tends to zero, the temperature will be -273.15ºC (Charles law). But shouldn't this number have some kind of error? And this would only apply to ideal gases.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37743/

Comment: The -273.15 degrees appears to be a definition. http://www1.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter2/2-1/2-1-1/kelvin.html Found that link through the Wikipedia article on absolute zero: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero

Comment: @BMS: Although it's now a matter of definition, there's a reason for the definition. The reason is the one given by George E. Smith.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/60860/5026

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the real question should be why is there a °C (Celsius).

The Celsius scale is a "Centigrade" scale in that it uniformly divides the temperature range between the boiling point of water, and the freezing point of water into 100 equal parts, and then it arbitrarily calls the freezing point zero °C, and the boiling point becomes 100°C.

The Kelvin scale is referenced to the triple point of water, not the freezing point, and that Temperature is about 0.1°C  (it might be 0.098°C but I am not sure about that).

Quite arbitrarily, it was decided that degrees on the Kelvin scale, should be identical in size to Celsius degrees, and experimentally the zero on the Kelvin scale (zero kelvins) is 273.16 Celsius degrees below the triple point of water, which makes it also 
-273.15°C

Comment: You say "experimentally the zero on the Kelvin scale (zero kelvins) is 273.16". But doesn't every measurement have some error +-something?

Comment: @jinawee the kelvin (and the deg centrigrade) is defined such that the triple point of water is 273.16K. So 0k is fixed by definition, if measurements change the triple point it will just change the size of a degree. The same thing happens with 'c' and the metre

Comment: @MartinBeckett Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Why does 'c' have so many significant figures compared to 273.16?

Comment: @jinawee because we had an existing definition of the meter which was very accurately measured, so the new one had to fit that. If we made a new 'm' now it would probably be c=300,000,000 m/s. We did this with the inch which is now 25.4mm exactly everywhere.

Comment: I'm in general agreement with most of what the other commenters have said.   Yes, experimental measurements do have uncertainties in them, and those uncertainties have to be considered.   In the case of the meter; and by inference, the value of "c" it was considered important to try and maintain historical continuity.  Eventually, metrology became so accurate, that it was clearly absurd, to try and measure a scratch on a metal bar.  Eventually, c and its components, mu,nought and epsilon,nought were defined as absolutes with no error.  So is the triple point of water, at 273.16 K

Answer (score 1):

"Kelvin" and "degrees Celsius" are defined such that there are **273.16** degrees between absolute zero and the **triple point** temperature of water. Degrees Celsius are defined as $K - 273.15$.

These [definitions have been in place since 1967](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/kelvin.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed defined as the temperature for which an ideal gas reaches a zero volume. Or that's how the definition is based. This number has an error altough I can't seem to find it anywhere, they probably did a lot of experiments so that the error is much smaller than the value -273.15°C that's used for 0K.

Answer (score 0):

You are outlining the earliest attempts to understand the value of absolute zero. However, once the concept of absolute zero was realized, scientists would have created other methods to probe this value including trying to create an environment with a temperature as close to absolute zero as possible.
In 2018, the Institute of Photonic Sciences in Spain were able to cool atoms to 0.00036 Kelvin based on measurements of the frequency of photons emitted from the atoms at that temperature. They used a method of laser cooling to achieve this low temperature.
So, to answer your question, it was originally deduced theoretically but later confirmed by various experimental methods.
Then metrology steps in as the unit of measurement for the Kelvin is defined as 1/273.16th of the difference between absolute zero and the triple point of water.

Comment: In 2013 folks got under a nanoKelvin (https://news.mit.edu/2003/cooling).